# Event for when a node is inserted into the DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, mutation-observers

I'm creating a DOMNode in JavaScript:

```
node = document.createElement("input")
```

I want to bind to an event that fires when it's inserted into the document.

Currently I'm using:

```
node.addEventListener("DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument", observe)
```

That method is deprecated. Is there an alternative method I can use that has the same effect?

The issue is that the node has certain bindings that need to be applied when it's in the document, and I want to clean them up when the node is removed, or re-apply them if the node is removed and re-inserted.

Comment: [MDN: Mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events) suggests using the [MutationObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) instead. Browser compatibility may be an issue though.

Comment: Here's a link that gives an example how to use _MutationObserver_   [How to use Mutation Events](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/)

Comment: I think you're making life difficult by needing to learn/include/maintain/worry about incompatibilities etc if you start using a library where you could simply use a closure/function call to tell you when the node is removed/re-inserted. Or maybe add an event to the node which uses setInterval() to tell you it has been added/removed.

Comment: Fares M. That's an interesting example, but I'm not sure how it applies to detecting when a node I create is inserted into the document, unless it's suggesting binding a mutation observer on the document itself and watching all node changes, but that seems a little heavy handed.

Comment: @user2356315 I'd prefer to avoid any setInterval type solutions because that makes unit testing slightly more difficult. It may be the case that I'll need to provide my own add/remove methods and hope people remember to use them, similar to how jQuery handles it.

Comment: I meet exactly the same problem: I create a lib that will build a component. User can get the root DOM node of this component and insert it wherever he wants in DOM tree. How can I know when this is done using MutationObservers ? I need to start some behaviours when the component is inserted in the document DOM. And I need also to detect whenever the component is removed and re-inserted anywhere else in the DOM tree.